# iOS App - Google Analytics Page View

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-analytics

I am nearing the end of the development for my app, I thought it would be a good idea to track usage, so I implemented Google Analytics.

I have this working nicely and have managed to track events. However, I would like to track a new page view using a variable as the trackPageView string. I have tried this so far:

```
 NSError *error;
    if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:titleString
                                         withError:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"new page track error");
    }
```

But this returns the NSLog error. So I then tried to use an event, like so:

```
    NSError *error;
    if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackEvent:@"show_page"
     action:@"show_page"
     label:titleString
     value:-1
     withError:&error]) {

         NSLog(@"event error");
}
```

After review the submitted data, both the Event Category and Event Action have been submitted, but no event label. How can I go about using a variable as the page view string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where/how is titleString defined? Are you SURE there's a value in there?

Comment: Have you tried reading the error parameter to see what the actual error is?